# Why doesn't Docusign revoke block access to my app?

Tags: docusignapi

My app is using JWT with individual consent. When, as a customer, I go to the Connected Apps screen at https://account-d.docusign.com/me/appconsent and revoke access to my app, the app still keeps working fine. No Docusign API calls fail, I can still create envelopes. Why? Is there another way to revoke?

The documentation page at https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/ says "In cases where user consent was provided by an organization administrator (such as the JWT Grant), this consent can be revoked with the DocuSign Admin tool." But there is no link with more if about this "Admin tool" and I can't find it, and I don't think this applies in my case since I'm using individual consent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the next time the app tries to use JWT to obtain an access token, it will fail.

But the already in use access token will continue to work until it expires at the end of its one hour lifetime.

If your experimentation doesn't support the above, please update your question.